# Refer js and css file in UIWebview in IOS?

Tags: javascript, css, uiwebview

In my app adding webview and its loading Html file but In my Html page I refere js and css file but not loaded.I followed many idea's given in stackoverflow but still not working.Can anyone please tell me your idea thank you?

Comment: Please Note that my js files are in nested folders.It is possible to have like nested folders?Xcode will support?

Answer (score 0):

Currently xcode does not refer java script files in nested folders So I gathered all files like (HTML,js,css files) and put them in other resources folder.It was automatically referred to compile sources in built phase.Make sure if not listed in Compile source just do the following .

Target->Build phases->click + button and add the resources like (HTML,js,css files).Now will work fine